# How can I rearrange the date from d-m-y to m-d-y in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

I am having issues with the following R code. I am trying to rearrange csv date values in a column from day-month-year to month-day-year. To issues arise: the format is changed to year-month-day instead, and this error message appears when I attempt to plot the results:

> Error: Column `New_Date` is a date/time and must be stored as POSIXct, not POSIXlt.

I am new to R and unsure on how to fix this error.

I have gone through a lot of similar topics, however because of lack of knowledge in R, I am unable to understand whether these topics can translate to my own code, and the information that I need.

Any help is much appreciated. The code is due relatively soon, so any fast responses are going to be worshipped. Thanks!

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(48L, 11L, 36L, 35L, 1L, 14L
), .Label = c("01-02-18", "02-03-18", "02-10-18", "03-01-18", 
"03-04-18", "03-05-18", "03-08-18", "03-09-18", "05-07-18", "05-12-18", 
"07-02-18", "07-06-18", "07-11-18", "08-03-18", "09-01-18", "09-05-18", 
"09-08-18", "09-10-18", "10-01-18", "10-04-18", "10-09-18", "11-07-18", 
"12-11-18", "12-12-18", "13-02-18", "13-06-18", "14-03-18", "14-09-18", 
"15-01-18", "15-05-18", "16-04-18", "16-08-18", "17-07-18", "18-12-18", 
"19-01-18", "19-02-18", "19-06-18", "19-10-18", "19-11-18", "20-03-18", 
"20-04-18", "20-08-18", "20-09-18", "21-05-18", "23-07-18", "23-11-18", 
"24-12-18", "25-01-18", "25-02-18", "25-05-18", "25-06-18", "25-10-18", 
"26-03-18", "26-09-18", "27-04-18", "29-08-18", "30-07-18", "31-05-18", 
"31-10-18"), class = "factor"), New_Date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(25L, 7L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 8L), mon = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L), year = c(-1882L, -1882L, -1882L, -1882L, 
-1882L, -1882L), wday = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L), yday = c(24L, 
37L, 49L, 18L, 31L, 66L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    zone = c("LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT", "LMT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    )), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:
Now having this error appear: "'Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values"
Below is my code:

```
beaches$Date = as.Date(as.character(beaches$Date), '%d-%m-%y')
beaches$New_Date = format(beaches$Date, '%m-%d-%y')
Palm_beach = filter(beaches, Site == "Palm Beach")
Shelly_beach = filter(beaches, Site == "Shelly Beach (Manly)")
plot(Palm_beach$Date, Palm_beach$Enterococci..cfu.100ml., col = "green", main = "Palm Beach vs Shelly Beach", xlab = "Dates", ylab = "Enterococci (cfu)")
points(Shelly_beach$Date, Shelly_beach$Enterococci..cfu.100ml., col = "red")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you kindly paste the output of `dput(head(beaches$date))`? It will look something like `structure(...)`.

Comment: The first one is the original Date column, where the second is the New_Date new column which I tried to make from the first. Thanks for the advice, will use that from now on!

Comment: I think the issue regards the `factor` format of `Date`. Can you supply an output of `dput(head(beaches))` instead of only the `Date` column?

Comment: I am now receiving this error when I try to plot the graphs 'Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values'

Comment: The generic one I believe? I am not entirely sure how to check. The code works when I run it line by line, however it does not work when I run all the lines of code at once.

Comment: I understand now; the y-axis should have the cfu of Enterococci bacteria. I have broken up the code into separate segments, and that seems to have fixed the finite xlim values error. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: Yes, I realised that, and the credit should go to you for your thorough help. I appreciate it. The code appears to work now on the first run, however the error 'Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values' persists after the second run of the code. Is there any obvious reason for this that I am not able to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
beaches$Date = as.Date(as.character(beaches$Date), '%d-%m-%y')
beaches$New_Date = format(beaches$Date, '%m-%d-%y')
```

Output:

```
> head(beaches[, c('Date', 'New_Date')])
        Date New_Date
1 2018-01-25 01-25-18
2 2018-02-07 02-07-18
3 2018-02-19 02-19-18
4 2018-01-19 01-19-18
5 2018-02-01 02-01-18
6 2018-03-08 03-08-18
```

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much, your help and patience is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since neither input nor output are dates it might make more sense to just use regular expresions, rather than converting to and from dates:

```r
beaches$New_Date <- sub("(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)", "\\2-\\1-\\3", beaches$Date)

#### OUTPUT ####

      Date New_Date
1 25-01-18 01-25-18
2 07-02-18 02-07-18
3 19-02-18 02-19-18
4 19-01-18 01-19-18
5 01-02-18 02-01-18
6 08-03-18 03-08-18
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to make sure that the original `Date` column is in character format. 
In your data it is in `factor` format. Then you first have to convert the `Date` column to a date format and then you can create the `New_Date` column:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format = "%d-%m-%y")
df$New_Date <- format(df$Date, "%m-%d-%Y")
```

If you only want the last two digits of the year column you can use this instead:

```
df$New_Date2 <- format(df$Date, "%m-%d-%y")
```