# Convert strange formate character date to date in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time, as.date

I have a dataset Peil_1 with column "timestamp" representing the time "value" was measured.

```
# A tibble: 175,350 x 5
   Timestamp                     Value `Quality Code` `Absolute Value` `AV Quality Code`
   <chr>                         <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>
 1 2014-11-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 0.712             10             12.4                10
 2 2014-11-01T00:15:00.000+01:00 0.712             10             12.4                10
 3 2014-11-01T00:30:00.000+01:00 0.712             10             12.4                10
 4 2014-11-01T00:45:00.000+01:00 0.712             10             12.4                10
 5 2014-11-01T01:00:00.000+01:00 0.712             10             12.4                10
 6 2014-11-01T01:15:00.000+01:00 0.712             10             12.4                10
 7 2014-11-01T01:30:00.000+01:00 0.712             10             12.4                10
 8 2014-11-01T01:45:00.000+01:00 0.713             10             12.4                10
 9 2014-11-01T02:00:00.000+01:00 0.713             10             12.4                10
10 2014-11-01T02:15:00.000+01:00 0.713             10             12.4                10
# ... with 175,340 more rows
```

I want to convert Peil_1$timestamp to a time or date format. I thought to use as.date, but I don't know how to handle the T00: 00: 00,000 + 1: 00 part

Comment: Hi, can you please post the output of `dput(head(Peil_1$Timestamp))` inside your question?
In the meanwhile you can check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656245/how-can-i-rearrange-the-date-from-d-m-y-to-m-d-y-in-r/58656728#58656728)

Comment: Try `lubridate::ymd_hms(Peil_1$timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually `as.Date` seems to work for me:

```
x <- "2014-11-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"
as.Date(x)

[1] "2014-11-01"
```

It appears that `as.Date` only checks if the format mask matches starting from the left of the text date, and ignores the rest.  Hence, the following text timestamp can also be converted to a date:

```
x <- "2014-11-01 Jon Skeet"
as.Date(x)

[1] "2014-11-01"
```